# Generate xml file with encoding "UCS-2 LE BOM"?

Tags: qt

I am trying to create an xml file with the encoding "UCS-2 LE BOM" in Qt. How do I do so?

Comment: You should change the file's encoding. Use a library, such as ICU.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. When using QTextStream, use setGenerateByteOrderMark(true) and codec to "UTF-16LE", the output will then show
with encoding "UCS-2 LE BOM".